# Using javascript variable Value form outside the method

Tags: javascript, scope

This is the function which I am using to get Table row number

```
$('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
    var rownum=$(this).index()
  alert('You clicked row '+ (rownum) );
});
```

The variable `rownum` I want to use it for further processing. But I am not able to get the value outside it. 
How to get it ?

I have tried as [suggested here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_scope_window).

```
<script>
find();
  alert('You clicked row '+ (window.rownum) );
</script>
```

But it did not worked out for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can to this.

What you have currently would work with a little modification:

```
var rownum;
$('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
  rownum=$(this).index()
  alert('You clicked row '+ (rownum) );
});
```

Hovever, the preferred method would be to pass the variable where it's needed:

```
function alertRowNumber(rowNumber) {
  alert('You clicked row '+ (rowNumber) );
}

$('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
  alertRowNumber($(this).index)
});
```

There may be an even better solution for your specific scenario, if you want to post an in-context snippet.

Answer (score 2):

```
  <script langguage='text/javascript'>  
    var rownum = "";
    $('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
      rownum=$(this).index();
      alert('You clicked row '+ (rownum) );
    });
 </script>
```

Do not use`var`, just define `rownum` outside so it will be global and you can access anywhere. Also you can not call `find()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `rownum` global and access from outside of the function:

```
var rownum;
$('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
  rownum = $(this).index();
  alert('You clicked row '+ (rownum) );
});
```

Or pass it `rownum` as parameter to other function

```
$('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
  var rownum = $(this).index();      
  myOtherFunction(rownum);
});

function myOtherFunction(num)(){
  alert(num)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `rownum` directly below `script` tag

```
<script type=text/javascript>
var rownum;

function A(){
    rownum=5;
}
function B(){
    alert(rownum);//will throw 5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespacing technique.

```
SomeNameSpace={} // Creating name spacing object
   SameNameSpace.rownum='';
   $('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
      SameNameSpace.rownum=$(this).index()
      alert('You clicked row '+ (SameNameSpace.rownum) );
    });
```

So anywhere you can use this variable by simply calling `SameNameSpace.rownum`

Using global variable may create issues in later, as other developer may create a variable by same name & in global space that will be a conflict

[Refer Here for more information on namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928926/what-advantages-are-gained-by-using-namespaces-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Make function any and you will get value for sure ...

```
 $('#myTable').find('tr').click( function(){
    rownum = $(this).index();
    //  alert('You clicked row '+ (rownum) );
    get(rownum);
 });

function get(rownum)
{
    alert(rownum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was how I did it using html5 session storage

```
//function to set line index on clicking a table row - note there were several tables so i selected the first using .eq();  

$("table").eq(0).on('click','tr',function () 
    {
        var lineNum = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        sessionStorage.setItem('lineNumber',lineNum);
    });

//the following retrieves the line index from session storage and converts it to a number from a string (all session storage values are stored as strings)

var line_Number=parseFloat(sessionStorage.getItem('lineNumber'));
```